# numpy.hstack gives: TypeError: _vhstack_dispatcher() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, numpy

I have this python code that takes in `Nx2` numpy array in which each row represents the `[x,y]` coordinates of one of the N points, and it returns an array of the same size containing transformed `[u,v]` coordinates for each point.

```
def inverse(arr):
    return np.hstack([arr[:, 0:1], arr[:, 1:2] - arr[:, 0:1]**2])
```

The transformation is defined as

```
u = x
v = y - x^2
```

This code works fine. But then I have the transformation

```
u = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
v = arctan2(y, x)
```

And the code is

```
def inverse(arr):
    return np.hstack(np.sqrt(arr[:, 0:1]**2 + arr[:, 1:2]**2), np.arctan2(arr[:, 1:2], arr[:, 0:1]))
```

But this code gives the following error:

```
TypeError: _vhstack_dispatcher() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What could be the reason for this? How can I fix this?

Comment: You are missing the square brackets in the second function. `hstack` expects a *sequence* as input.

Answer (score 0):

np.hstack() or np.vstack() expects a set of arrays in the form of list or tuple in the parameters. In your code, you have given two arrays separately, therefore it is considering them as 2 inputs while it takes one as a tuple of 2 different arrays. So just put "( )" around the parameters in the hstack() function and your code will work fine..

wrong code:

```
def inverse(arr):
return np.hstack(np.sqrt(arr[:, 0:1]**2 + arr[:, 1:2]**2), np.arctan2(arr[:, 1:2], arr[:, 0:1]))
```

The correct code:

```
def inverse(arr):
return np.hstack((np.sqrt(arr[:, 0:1]**2 + arr[:, 1:2]**2), np.arctan2(arr[:, 1:2], arr[:, 0:1])))
```

Answer (score -1):

here

```
def inverse(arr):
   return np.hstack([np.sqrt(arr[:, 0:1]**2 + arr[:, 1:2]**2), np.arctan2(arr[:,1:2], arr[:, 0:1])])
```